# Bulk set the environment variables in Heroku pipeline

Tags: heroku

I am trying to bulk set the environment variables for a Heroku pipeline since Heroku does not use the parent's environment variables in the pipeline anymore in the new version.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/review-apps-new#configuration

I tried these but they don't work. I couldn't find any documentation for this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
heroku config:set KEY1=VALUE1 KEY2=VALUE2 --app my-pipeline

heroku config:set KEY1=VALUE1 KEY2=VALUE2 --pipeline=my-pipeline
```

Comment: Hello @myo, The above command is working for me. Can you please post the error you are receiving?   Please note --app expects heroku app name.,/

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all env var from another app as described [here](https://help.heroku.com/RVEKYMZQ/how-to-copy-staging-dev-production-application-config-variable-to-review-app-config-vars):

```
CONFIG_VARS=$(echo $(heroku config -a APPLICATION_NAME --json)) && curl -n -X PATCH https://api.heroku.com/pipelines/PIPELINE_ID}/stage/review/config-vars -d "$CONFIG_VARS" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

Switch out `APPLICATION_NAME` with your app name and `PIPELINE_ID` witht the id of the pipeline you want to copy config vars to.